# login incorrect - fresh 12.04 server install

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, login

I have installed ubuntu server a few times today.  The first time I installed it to a USB drive and it worked just fine.  But it was too slow.

Then I removed that drive and installed again on a hard drive.  I did this from both USB and CD with the same result:
After install and restart, I cannot login with the user and password I set during the install.  I get the following error: 
"Login Incorrect"

I am a noob to linux, so may need more specific directions around a fix. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Check if Caplocks is on .If you want to restore password refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password) .

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I unplugged all drives except the target for the install and it works.